# Topological sort (Grafos)

Tags: python, python-3.x

He estado estudiado el tema de los grafos en python, y me encontre con el Topological-Sort que es un método de ordenamiento de grafos; pero aun no entiendo del todo bien como realizar este método en python, se la teoría de este ordenamiento y como debería servir pero no se como aplicarlo a python, por ejemplo:

> Tenemos un grado de 6 nodos, cuyas uniones son las siguientes:
>   (5,2),(5,0),(4,0),(4,1),(2,3),(3,1).

Con esto podemos saber el ***'Peso'*** de cada nodo que serian:

> peso de 5 -> 0
>   peso de 4 -> 0
>   peso de 3 -> 1
>   peso de 2 -> 1
>   peso de> 1 -> 1
>   peso de 0 -> 2

entonces el ordenamiento de menor a mayor seria: ***5 4 2 3 1 0***

Mi duda es de como sirven los códigos de python que hacen este ordenamiento ya que quiero implementar uno pero no estoy seguro de como hacerlo.
Aquí muestro un código que he encontrado:

```
#Python program to print topological sorting of a DAG
from collections import defaultdict

#Class to represent a graph
class Graph:
    def __init__(self,vertices):
        self.graph = defaultdict(list) #dictionary containing adjacency List
        self.V = vertices #No. of vertices

    # function to add an edge to graph
    def addEdge(self,u,v):
        self.graph[u].append(v)

    # A recursive function used by topologicalSort
    def topologicalSortUtil(self,v,visited,stack):

        # Mark the current node as visited.
        visited[v] = True

        # Recur for all the vertices adjacent to this vertex
        for i in self.graph[v]:
            if visited[i] == False:
                self.topologicalSortUtil(i,visited,stack)

        # Push current vertex to stack which stores result
        stack.insert(0,v)

    # The function to do Topological Sort. It uses recursive 
    # topologicalSortUtil()
    def topologicalSort(self):
        # Mark all the vertices as not visited
        visited = [False]*self.V
        stack =[]

        # Call the recursive helper function to store Topological
        # Sort starting from all vertices one by one
        for i in range(self.V):
            if visited[i] == False:
                self.topologicalSortUtil(i,visited,stack)

        # Print contents of stack
        print stack
```

referencia: [Topological-sort-code](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/topological-sorting/)

Solo estoy solicitando una pequeña guia de como funciona este codigo para yo poder implementar mi propio codigo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lo que supuestamente hace el algoritmo lo explica la misma página que has referenciado. Cito textualmente (traduciendo):

> [...] En la ordenación topológica, usamos una pila temporal. No imprimimos el vértice inmediatamente, sino que primero llamamos a la función de ordenación topológica, recursivamente, para todos sus vértices adyacentes, y después lo metemos en la pila. Finalmente imprimimos los contenidos de la pila. Observa que un vértice debe ser guardado en la pila sólo cuando todos sus vértices adyacentes (y los adyacentes de éstos, etc.) están ya en la pila.

Hay una palabra clave aquí que debes comprender para que todo tenga sentido, y es **recursivamente**. Esto significa que la misma función a la que llamas para que ordene un grafo partiendo de un vértice dado `v`, es la que se llama para que ordene los sub-grafos que comienzan en cada uno de los vecinos de `v`. Es decir, la función se llama a sí misma. Aunque puede ser difícil seguir en la cabeza el orden en que suceden las llamadas, este mecanismo (recursión) proporciona no obstante una forma más sencilla de describir cómo debe resolverse el problema.

Veamos ahora un poco más detenidamente el código.

### La estructura de datos

El grafo se guarda en un par de variables de la clase:

- `V`, que es un número indicando cuántos vértices tiene el grafo
- `graph` que es un diccionario cuyas claves son los "nombres" (números) de los vértices y los valores la lista de vértices adyacentes de cada uno de ellos.

Así, por ejemplo, para el grafo `(5,2),(5,0),(4,0),(4,1),(2,3),(3,1)` que mencionas en tu enunciado, y que tendría este aspecto:

[image: grafo]

las variables antes mencionadas serían:

- `V` = 6
- `graph={0: [], 1: [], 2: [3], 3: [1], 4: [0, 1], 5: [2, 0]}`

El diccionario muestra que el nodo `0` no tiene vecinos (recuerda que es un grafo dirigido, por tanto los vecinos serían los apuntados por flechas que *salgan* de ese nodo). Lo mismo le pasa al nodo 1. El nodo 2 tiene un vecino, que es 3. El 3 tiene uno, que es 1, el 4 tiene dos (0 y 1) y el 5 también tiene dos (2 y 0). Esta estructura por tanto representa correctamente el grafo de la figura.

La misión de la ordenación topológica es mostrar los nodos en un orden tal que si hay una flecha entre los nodos A y B, A aparezca antes que B en la ordenación final.

La "pila" usada por el algoritmo tiene esta misión. Un nodo nuevo sólo se mete en la pila si en la pila ya estaban todos sus vecinos, y los vecinos de éstos.

Por ejemplo, imagina que la pila está vacía y estamos considerando si hay que meter en ella el nodo 2. La respuesta será que "NO", porque 2 tiene un vecino (3) que no está en la pila. Sin embargo si nos preguntamos si hay que meter el nodo 1, la respuesta sería "SI", porque el nodo 1 no tiene vecinos y por tanto puede ir a la pila sin más.

Ahora imagina que la pila tiene un elemento, por ejemplo el 3, y sólo ese. ¿Podría ir a la pila ahora el elemento 2? La respuesta es de nuevo "NO" porque aunque su vecino (el 2) sí está en la pila, los vecinos del 2 no están (en realidad esta situación no podria darse ya que el 2 nunca debía haber entrado en la pila antes, hasta que no esté el 1).

### El algoritmo recursivo

Como ves, es difícil decidir en qué orden recorrer los elementos para que vayan guardándose en la pila en orden correcto.

El truco es, los recorro en cualquier órden (por ejemplo, en orden numérico, del 0 al 5), pero guardo en otra variable qué nodos he examinado ya. Para cada nodo, si no lo he examinado, lo marco como examinado y llamo a la misma función para que meta en la pila a todos sus vecinos, y luego meto al nodo en cuestión.

Es decir, en pseudocódigo, dado un nodo `v` la función `Ordenar` haría lo siguiente:

1. Lo marca como visitado
2. Para cada vecino de `v` que no haya sido visitado, llama otra vez a `Ordenar()`, pasándole ese vecino.
3. Mete en la pila `v`

### Ejemplo de ejecución

Parece casi milagroso que un algoritmo tan simple pueda funcionar, pero lo hace. Es la magia de la recursión, hace fácil escribir el algoritmo, pero difícil imaginar su ejecución. Vamos a ello.

Hay que llamar a `Ordenar()` para cada nodo del grafo, y dejar que la recursión haga su magia. Al final, imprimir la pila.

- Empezamos por el nodo 0. Lo marco visitado. Ya que no tiene vecinos no hay que llamar recursivamente a `Ordenar()`. Lo metemos en la pila.

  ```
  pila = [0]
  ```
- Pasamos al nodo 1. Lo marco visitado. Ya que tampoco tiene vecinos, no hay llamadas recursivas. A la pila!

  ```
  pila = [1, 0]
  ```
- Vamos al nodo 2. Lo marco visitado. Este nodo (mira la figura) tiene un vecino, el 3, que aún no ha sido visitado. Así que llamo de nuevo a `Ordenar` pasándole ahora el 3. Sólo cuando esta segunda llamada a `Ordenar()` haya retornado seguiremos en la llamada original y meteremos 2 en la pila.

  - Segunda llamada de `Ordenar()`, recibe el 3. Lo marca como visitado. Mira la lista de vecinos de 3, y vemos el 1, pero el 1 ya ha sido marcado como visitado, por lo que no tiene que llamar otra vez a `Ordenar()`. Metemos el 3 en la pila.

    ```
    pila = [3, 1, 0]
    ```

    y retornamos

  La llamada recursiva terminó, metemos el 2 en la pila

  ```
  pila = [2, 3, 1, 0]
  ```
- Vamos al nodo 3, pero está ya marcado como visitado. No hay que hacer nada
- Vamos al nodo 4, lo marcamos como visitado. Su lista de vecinos es 0 y 1, y ambos han sido visitados, por lo que no hay llamada recursiva. Metemos el 4 en la pila

  ```
  pila = [4, 2, 3, 1, 0]
  ```
- Vamos al nodo 5, lo marcamos como visitado. Su lista de vecinos es 2 y 0, ambos ya visitados. No hay llamada recursiva, y metemos 5 en la pila.

Hemos terminado y tenemos:

```
pila = [5, 4, 2, 3, 1, 0]
```

Basta imprimir esa pila en ese orden, que cumplirá la propiedad buscada.

### Sobre la implementación

En la implementación python a la que has enlazado, lo que he llamado `Ordenar()` sería `topologicalSortUtil()`, mientras que el "programa principal" que va recorriendo los nodos de 0 a 5 y llamando a `Ordenar()` sería `topologicalSort()`.

El código en cuestión es farragoso de leer porque a  `topologicalSortUtil()` le pasa no sólo el vértice que se está considerando, sino también la lista de visitados y la propia pila para que la vaya actualizando.

Me parece que esa implementación puede simplificarse mucho sacando la lista de visitados y la pila a variables del objeto (p.ej: `self.visited` y `self.stack`, con lo que ya no habría que pasarlos como parámetros, sino que serían "compartidas" entre las diferentes llamadas a `Ordenar()`, recursivas o no.

## Actualización

A continuación va una implementación minimalista de lo explicado anteriormente. He simplificado muchas cosas con respecto a la implementación de la web que enlazabas. Las más importantes:

- No uso clases ni orientación a objetos, para simplificar. Todo son funciones y variables globales
- No doy funciones para crear el grafo añadiendo enlaces entre sus nodos. En vez de eso el grafo debe darse directamente como diccionario.
- Sólo tengo dos variables globales: el grafo en sí (almacenado directamente en forma de diccionario) y la "pila" que guardará la ordenación final. He eliminado la variable `visitados` por superflua, pues podemos igualmente saber si un nodo ha sido ya vistado si aparece en la pila.
- La función ordenar recibe ahora sólo el nodo a considerar, el resto de información que necesita (el grafo y la pila) los toma de las variables globales.

El código queda ahora tan sencillo como esto, donde se ve mucho más claramente el funcionamiento del algoritmo como fue explicado más arriba.

```
grafo = {0: [], 1: [], 2: [3], 3: [1], 4: [0, 1], 5: [2, 0]}
pila = []

def ordenar(nodo):
  for vecino in grafo[nodo]:
    if vecino not in pila:
      ordenar(vecino)
  pila.insert(0,nodo)

def main():
  for nodo in grafo:
    if nodo not in pila:
      ordenar(nodo)  
  print(pila)

main()
# Imprime: [5, 4, 2, 3, 1, 0]
```

Comment: Excelente respuesta!

Comment: @David.O Gracias. La he actualizado con un código muy simplificado, pues la implementación de la web que enlazabas no me gustaba nada.